# FuelSDK-PHP in not working in 5.2.3 php version

Tags: fuel-sdk

I am running my site on php 5.2.3 version when I am using FuelSDK-PHP to subscribe email to list, is not working. in ET_Client.php is saying '**DIR**' and 'DateInterval' Which supports on php 5.3 and above.

Can some one help to solve this problem

Thanks
Srinivas